# Count the no of Consecutive no greater then threshold value but groupwise in a Given data frame

Tags: r

Let say we need to count consecutive number greater then 40 but groupwise(tag) such that counting of consecutive number shall be independent of Tag.

For example we have 6 group from tag column so for every group we will be calculating how many times temp variable has crossed threshold value.Below is reproducible example i tried to present along with this i pasted a snap of expected output.

```
tag<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5,
        6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)
temp<- c(43, 44, 45, 41, 43, 38, 40, 41, 39, 37, 37, 39, 45, 42, 41, 43, 44, 39,38,
         37, 43, 44, 45, 41, 43, 38, 40, 41, 39, 37, 37, 39, 45, 42, 41, 43, 44, 
        39, 38, 37, 43, 44, 45, 41, 43, 38, 40, 41, 39, 37, 37, 39, 45, 42, 41,43,
         44, 39, 38, 37)

df=data.frame(tag=tag,temp=temp)
```

Expected output is the third column status

[image]

Comment: I think there is a typo.  Your third group should start at Sr. No: 21

Comment: @akrun yes its typo error , i agree on this sir Requesting you ,can you plz explain the code that would be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), create a grouping variable using the run-length-id of the logical vector (`temp >= 40`), Grouped by 'tag', 'grp' and set the `i` with logical condition, we assign 'status' as the sequence of rows (`seq_len(.N)`), and convert the 'NA' elements in 'status' to 0

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)[, grp := rleid(temp >= 40)][temp >= 40, status := seq_len(.N) , .(tag, grp)
             ][is.na(status), status := 0][]
head(df, 20)    
#    tag temp grp status
# 1:   1   43   1      1
# 2:   1   44   1      2
# 3:   1   45   1      3
# 4:   1   41   1      4
# 5:   1   43   1      5
# 6:   1   38   2      0
# 7:   1   40   3      1
# 8:   1   41   3      2
# 9:   1   39   4      0
#10:   1   37   4      0
#11:   2   37   4      0
#12:   2   39   4      0
#13:   2   45   5      1
#14:   2   42   5      2
#15:   2   41   5      3
#16:   2   43   5      4
#17:   2   44   5      5
#18:   2   39   6      0
#19:   2   38   6      0
#20:   2   37   6      0
```

---

Or using `rle` from `base R`.  We use `ave` to group by 'tag', get the `rle` of the logical vector (`temp >=40`), replicate the `values` by the `lengths` and multiply it with the `sequence` of `lengths`.  The `TRUE/FALSE` values coerced to `1/0` and when multiplying a number with 1, it returns that number while with 0, we get the 0 value.

```
df$status <-  with(df, ave(temp >= 40, tag, FUN = function(x) {
           rl <- rle(x)
          with(rl, sequence(lengths) * rep(values, lengths))}))
df$status 
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
#[26] 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0
```